# How does this system accelerate?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, classical-mechanics, acceleration, string

Suppose m1= 1kg, m2= 2kg, m3= 3kg
Then what could be the acceleration?
[image: 2 pulley system]

Comment: Hi Vivek and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that we don't answer homework or worked example type questions. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework/exercise questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Answer (score 2):

m1 goes up, m2 goes up, m3 goes down

Do you want numbers?

Comment: Yes, i need to know what would be the acceleration of each masses. I tried to figure it out but it confuses me due to the relative acceleration between m2 & m3